# how to configure the url path in web.xml web application's setting file?

Tags: java, web-services, jetty, web.xml

I have a web service project in Eclipse, I export the war file and deploy it in jetty, but then the application is found under the project name (localhost:8080/projectname/home/)

I want to configure it to be found under a different name than the project name (ex: localhost:8080/myname/home/).

how can I configure it to do so in web.xml? If that's not in web.xml, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deployment location is usually based on the WAR filename, but you can also set it up on the server in the jetty.xml file.

You can find more info on the naming conventions here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deploy_Web_Applications

And some info on contextDeployers here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/ContextDeployer

Answer (score 1):

Use [Maven Jetty plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin). Set the optional `<contextPath>` param.